# NameError "inputNames" is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, nameerror

I went through a ton of the other not defined posts and was unable to find my error, I am sure its something stupid and I am going to feel like an idiot. I am in my first programming class in college so I apologize for my ignorance. I do believe this is the only section of my code that is causing the error, if more is needed I will ad it. And thank you in advance!

```
def main():
    endProgram = 'no'
    playerOne = 'no'
    playerTwo = 'no'

playerOne, playerTwo = inputNames(playerOne, playerTwo)

def inputNames(playerOne, playerTwo):
    playerOne = raw_input('Enter number your name: ')
    print 'Welcome', playerOne, 'you are player one!'

    playerTwo = raw_input('Enter number your name: ')
    print 'Welcome', playerOTwo, 'you are player two!'

    return playerOne, playerTwo
```

Comment: It's not defined *until **after** you try to call it!*

Comment: As a side note, remember to stick to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) and use `underscore_casing`. Also if you're learning python, do learn python 3 first, as python 2 won't be supported in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jonrsharpe commented, you need to define the function before calling it:

```
def inputNames():
    playerOne = raw_input('Enter number your name: ')
    print 'Welcome', playerOne, 'you are player one!'

    playerTwo = raw_input('Enter number your name: ')
    print 'Welcome', playerTwo, 'you are player two!'

    return playerOne, playerTwo

def main():
    endProgram = 'no'
    playerOne = 'no'
    playerTwo = 'no'

playerOne, playerTwo = inputNames()
```

Notice that you were defining input parameters, which is wrong in this case because:

They aren't needed in this case

You werent passing any value to the parameters when calling the function, because of playerOne and playerTwo weren't defined outside the functions before calling inputNames()

Also, you made an error in line 12. Obviously, playerOTwo is not defined:

```
print 'Welcome', playerOTwo, 'you are player two!'
```

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

Originally you were practicing with parameter-based functions. This alternative solution will give some light about how parameters are used:

```
# Playernum is supposed to be an integer
def inputName(playernum):
    # This will trigger AssertionError if parameter is not integer
    assert type(playernum) == int

    name = raw_input('Enter your name: \n') # New line character='\n'
    print 'Welcome', name, 'you are player' + str(playernum)
    # return statement ends function if executed
    return name


def main():
    endProgram = 'no'
    playerOne = 'no'
    playerTwo = 'no'


playerOne, playerTwo = inputName(1), inputName(2)
```